# How do I change color of Scrollbar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, scrollbar, settings

The question is - **how do I change color of scrollbar in VSCode?**

I want to change my scrollbar to the color of my VSCode background. Available scrollbar settings in `workbench.colorCustomizations` don't change it the way I want (all I could find is `scrollBarSlider` and `scrollbar.shadow` settings), and I know there's a way to change it cause it is different in other themes (it's the same color as the background in those themes, as it should be)

[How my scrollbar looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Dg4.png)

(Added an arrow juuuuuust incase)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorOverviewRuler.background": "#ff0000",  // for the "track" where the scrollThumb lives
    "scrollbarSlider.background": "#9aa",  // for the scrollThumb color
}
```

For others, see [theme color reference: scrollbars](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#scrollbar-control) and `editorOverViewRuler` in the same link.

Do note that there are other indicators that also live in the `editorOverviewRuler`, like selection indicators, find match indicators and more, which have to play nice with the color as well.

Comment: I've found this already, as I stated in my answer, and this isn't what I am looking for. It's a scrollbar slider option, I need to change the scrollbar itself
Edit: `editorOverviewRuler.background` works great! I owe you man.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that what you want to change is the scrollTrack - see edited answer.

Comment: Just edited my comment too, thanks yet again!

Comment: See the cautionary note in the answer - there are various indicators that also are placed in the `editorOverviewRuler` - so you may have to adjust their color as well.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for such a detailed answer